# Подвиг, подвижник, подвизаться

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Со словом "подвиг" все понятно. Но, интересно, а слово "подвижник" родственно ему (не грамматически - это-то понятно, а по смыслу) или нет? Все-таки подвиг - это чаще какое-то, так сказать, единоразовое деяние, а подвижник - человек, который действует во имя кого-то или какой-то идеи ежедневно.
И еще есть слово "подвизаться". Тут вообще нет отношения к понятию самоотречения, как в первых двух случаях, но слово явно одного корня.
В общем, интересно было бы узнать, как все эти три слова связаны между собой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В быту эти слова стали применяться шире, чем раньше. Когда-то подвиг имел, прежде всего, религиозное значение. Попалась статья, связывающая все три понятия именно в этом смысле.
http://www.pravoslavie.ru/put/34048.htm
"Подвизаться – значит проходить какой-либо подвиг или совершать какое-либо трудное дело во спасение души своей."